# Find a first max value in an array

Tags: r

I have a array of data which is increased then decreased then increased again.  I I want to find the first max value, currently I am using a linear search and I wonder if there is a better way to do this in R.  Thank you 
A small sample of data:

```
x <-c(1.2,1.3,1.35,1.4,1.45,1.7,1.78,2,1.87,1.8,1.78,1.79,1.82,1.85,1.86,1.87)
data <-data.frame(x)
```

Comment: `min(which(diff(x) < 0))`

Comment: Ever so slightly more efficient: `which.min(diff(x) > 0)`

Comment: @Gregor, please help me to understand why it is slightly more efficient.  The answer from G5W gives me the index position, and from the index position, I can find the value.  I didn't have a correct answer from your suggestion yet, but I am very interesting in efficiency because I have a long list of values.  Thanks

Comment: When I define your `x` vector and run `min(which(diff(x) < 0))` I get 8, and when I run `which.min(diff(x) > 0)` I also get 8. So I think they both work correctly. I like G5W's answer because it's pretty clear what it does. Mine is trickier to figure out, but *slightly* more efficient because `which.min` is a tiny bit faster than a `min()` and a `which()` - and the difference will be bigger on longer vectors. However, unless your vector length is in millions and you are running this operation frequently, the difference isn't enough to matter.

Comment: Hi Gregor, I still don't know I always have a different answer when I ran your code and G5W.  I enclosed below the copy from console, please let me know.  Thank you.                                                                                       >x<-c(1.2,1.3,1.35,1.4,1.45,1.7,1.78,2,1.87,1.8,1.78,1.79,1.82,1.85,1.86,1.87)
> data <-data.frame(x)
> val <-min(which(diff(x) < 0))
> val1 <- which.min(diff(x) < 0)
> print(val)
[1] 8
> print(val1)
[1] 1
>

Comment: Sorry, it was my error.  I have incorrect relational operator "< " instead of " >".  Thank you.